# Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks, stomp, stompjs

Within my handleSubmit method if I hardcode the message and publish the method works as intended. However if I replace "hello stomp" with the input state or submit with any input at all I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined" any insight here will be greatly appreciated

```
export const Comms = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const client = new Client();
  client.configure({
    brokerURL: "ws://localhost:2019/socket",
    reconnectDelay: 5000,
    heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
    heartbeatOutgoing: 4000,
    onConnect: function () {
      client.subscribe("/topic/messages", function (msg) {
        console.log("WS-MESSAGE: ", msg.body);
      });
    },
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    client.publish({ destination: "/topic/messages", body: "Hello stomp" });
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    client.activate();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="comms-cont">
      <h1 className="comms-header">Messaging</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-1">
        <input
          className="forminput"
          type="text"
          name="message"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setInput(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a controlled input component. Add the prop value to the input like this:

```
<input
 className="forminput"
 type="text"
 name="message"
 value={input}
 onChange={(e) => {
 setInput(e.target.value);
 }}
/>
```